# Unknown error caused by DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

Since a few days back the WPF editor no longer works. Whenever I click somewhere in any editor it becomes disabled with this message:

```
'NullReferenceException was thrown on "DataTemplate": ... (etc.)'
```

I have spent a few hours trying to locate the problem without success so if anyone could give a hint on where to look I would greatly appreciate it.

I have tried to debug with CLR exceptions enabled when thrown (VS2010->Debug->Exceptions...->Common Language Exceptions (Thrown) 'Checked') but I get no exceptions from it.

Apparently there's a problem some DataTemplate somewhere that's only showing in design time but I just can't figure out how to locate it.

Cheers

Comment: Try comment out your DataTemplate code and then uncomment portions of code to find out where the problem is.

Comment: Can't provide any constructive help without seeing the code.. I guess it's thrown somewhere in a ValueConverter

Comment: I realize it's impossible to provide a solution for this. The amount of code I would have to cut'n'paste is simply to large. I was mainly asking for advice, wondering if anyone has stumbled upon this issue before. It seems the issue is not really related to what's on screen at the moment. Creating a completely empty UserControl gives me a few minutes where I can mouse edit it but then the editor shuts down again with the same message. That tells me the problem is somewhere in the underlying WPF DataTemplate logics, making it extremely hard to locate.

Comment: I just had exactly the same problem. Reason was that I was using a custom markup extension with a nondefault constructor. I could solve the error message in the VS designer by adding the [ConstructorArgument] attribute as described here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/vswpfdesigner/thread/5120a064-2d1a-4f25-84f2-a36bb91c4200 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally traced the problem to a small markup extension I wrote. Having removed it the DataTemplaring system stopped behaving badly.